# PhpStorm - autocomplete in the html comment

Tags: autocomplete, phpstorm, webstorm

Is it possible to create the autocomplete value of class attribute for the html comment in PhpStorm?

That is, after updating the new value of class, it would automatically add this value in the commentary? In `emmet` and in the live template I could only once, at start create this comment but after update it doesn't work..

For example:

```
<tag class="class1 class2 class3">...</tag>< !-- /.class1 class2 class2
```

Comment: IDE has no functionality of such kind to update existing sutff -- only when writing  a fresh code (as you have mentioned already: using Emmet or Live Templates)